# AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'update_bullets'

Tags: python, pygame

As a beginner, I was trying the "Alien invasion' project in the *python crash course a hands-on project-based introduction to programming* and got stuck, I was just trying to copy the code but it always get the same feedback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/snake/venv/Alien_Invasion/main_game.py", line 29, in <module>
 run_game()
 File "D:/snake/venv/Alien_Invasion/main_game.py", line 26, in run_game
 bullets.update_bullets()
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'update_bullets'
```

and here's my code:

main_game.py

```
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
import bullet


def run_game():
    #初始化游戏并创建一个屏幕对象
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien_Invasion")

    #创建一艘飞船
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    #创建一个子弹编组
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    #游戏主循环
    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update_ship()
        bullets.update_bullets()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
"""一个对飞船发射的子弹管理的类"""

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """在飞船所在位置创建一个子弹对象"""
    self.screen = screen
    super(Bullet, self).__init__()

    #在（0，0）处创建一个表示子弹的矩形，在放置到正确的位置
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
        ai_settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    #存储用小数表示的子弹位置
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update_bullets(self):
    """向上移动子弹"""
    #更新浮点数的子弹纵坐标
    self.y -= self.speed_factor

    #更新子弹纵坐标位置
    self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
    """在屏幕上绘制子弹"""
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame


def check_keydown_event(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    #创建一个子弹，并加入bullets编组
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_event(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """响应按键和鼠标事件"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_event(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_event(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """更新屏幕上的图像并切换到新屏幕"""
    #每次循环时都重新绘制屏幕
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    #在飞船和外星人后面重绘所有子弹
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()

    #最近绘制屏幕可见
    pygame.display.flip()
```

there are two other files, but I don't think they are related to this problem.

settings.py

```
class Settings():
"""存储所有设置的类"""

def __init__(self):
    """初始化屏幕设置"""
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    #飞船速度
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

    #子弹设置
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_heght = 15
    self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings

    """"加载飞船并获取其外接矩形"""
    self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    """将每艘飞船放在屏幕中央底部"""
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    #创建属性center存储坐标小数值
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    #飞船移动标志
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False

def update_ship(self):
    """根据移动标志调整飞船位置"""
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    #根据center更新rect.centerx值
    self.rect.centerx = self.center

def blitme(self):
    """在指定位置绘制飞船"""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong here? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed `pygame` package in Project Interpreter in settings?

Comment: @sTekin, thanks for the comment and yes I have, the package worked fine in the previous steps.

Comment: @sTekin，btw, I only store a few values in the settings, may pygame is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your traceback error it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/snake/venv/Alien_Invasion/main_game.py", line 2, in <module>
from pygame import Group
importError: cannot import name 'Group' from 'pygame' (D:\snake\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py)
```

Which says there should be this line:

```
from pygame import Group
```

on line 2 of your main_game.py module. However in the code you have included, that is not there:

main_game.py

```
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
```

Are you sure you are showing he correct code?

Ignoring the code and just looking at the error message it shows that you had this line:

```
from pygame import Group
```

There is no `pygame.Group` which is why you are getting the error telling you that. I think you are looking for `pygame.sprite.Group`

Edit

Now that we have the right code and the right question :-)

Sprite groups have some built-in methods which can be seen in the docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). One of these is `update()` which will then call the `update()` function in all the sprites in the group. Your problem is that you named your sprite function `update_bullets()` not just `update()` and then you tried to call `update_bullets()` on the group and the group does not have that method.

So to fix your code you have to rename your `Bullet` method to just `update()` and then call the sprite.Group method `update()` to have it called on all the bullets in the group.

You have the same issue with your `draw_bullet()` method but you worked around it by iterating over the group and calling your method. That works, but you should correct it to take advantage of the builtin group method. You need to change it to just `draw()` and then you can call it on all the bullets by just calling `bullets.draw()`. As I said, in your code now, because you are not using the name that the sprite.Group knows how to find, you are iterating over the group. If you rename it, you can then replace this:

```
for bullet in bullets.sprites():
    bullet.draw_bullet()
```

with just:

```
bullets.draw()
```

Comment: thannks, you're right, I've copied an old version of my code. So I changed line 19 in main_game.py ' bullets = Group' to ' bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()' and the traceback is different too : 'Group' object has no attribute 'update_bullets' which is what I intended to ask about.

Comment: @rene3619 I have updated the answer to deal with your reworded question.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you've suggested, also corrected a few typos, and  it finally works !